# How to add easing effect to "mousemove" gallery thumbnails

Tags: jquery, mousemove, easing

Before I try to explain it all, please view here what I am talking about. This is the thumbnail view of a gallery. On mouseenter it starts moving but without any smooth easing effect. I think that makes it look very "nervous".

Please view here:
http://mark-i-mark.com/lab/test/index.html

The code snippet that is "running" the mousemove function can be viewed here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nWMY9/

Does have anybody a nice idea how to make it more smooth, based on the jQuery easing plugin? Help is really appreciated. If you need more info, please let me know.

**EDIT 05.12.2011**
**@roXon**
Your solution is exactly what I need. To make that happen with the gallery script, I want to update the information a little bit. Maybe you can make it happen.
A live preview of the gallery can be found here:
http://mark-i-mark.com/lab/smartajax/index.html

The js file is jquery.dob.WallGridGallery.js, the mousemove function starts at row 553 and ends at row 595. It now looks more organized that the last version.

Most of the dimensions are set dynamically by the script. Optional settings can be made in the xml file:
http://mark-i-mark.com/lab/smartajax/WallGridGallery/xml/SettingsWallGridGallery.xml

If no settings are made, it takes the visible size of the gallery from what you have set for the #galleryContainer in the html markup BUT the dimensions of the thumbnailsWrapper is calculated dynamically.

The goal would be to include your cool movement solution in the existing script. Do you think you could do that? I hope I have provided all information you may need, otherwise let me know. Thanks for sharing that challenge with me. I think that the gallery would look so much better with your solution included.

Comment: One quick though would be not to link the sliding motion to the mouse movement. Instead, set a point on the left side and the right that starts a sliding animation when the mouse goes beyond the points. So for example, if the mouse is within 50px of the left edge, then just trigger a continuous scroll. Same for the right side...

Comment: I have updated the html file. The thumb container, actually, is moving in all directions, as can be seen now. I think I need another aproach but thank you anyway for the fast shot.

Comment: It's hard to implement my code into your giant. ...My hands are crossed. I gave you just an idea on how to do it, I miss the source and have not much time to inspect your code and write-rewrite-test my implementations. My best suggestion is that you build your self a better gallery.